# Как сделать автоматическое изменение поля Text при выборе определенного значения Picker

Tags: swift, swiftui

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы при выборе определенного значения из поля Picker автоматически менялся результат в поле Text. Написал код, но выдает ошибку Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'. Вот код:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012"]
    @State private var selectedYearIndex = 2
    @State private var resultText = ""
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        switch selectedYearIndex {
        case 0:
            self.resultText = "Hello"
        case 1:
            self.resultText = "Hi"
        case 2:
            self.resultText = "Bye"
        default:
            self.resultText = "No"
        }
        
        VStack {
            Text("Result Text:")
            Spacer()
            Text("\(resultText)")
            Spacer()
            
            Picker("Choose a Year", selection: $selectedYearIndex) {
                
                ForEach(0..<years.count) {
                    Text("\(years[$0])").font(.title)
                }
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант решения:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var years: [String] = ["2010", "2011", "2012"]
    let strings: [String] = ["Hello", "Hi", "Bye"]
    @State private var selectedYear = "2010"
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Please choose a year", selection: $selectedYear) {
                ForEach(years, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }
            }
            Text("You selected: \(strings[years.firstIndex(of: selectedYear) ?? 0])")
        }
    }
}
```

у вас ошибка потому что нельзя размещать такого рода куски кода который возвращает какую-то вьюху.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.